# Save application data on closing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm coding a Phone book. It's fully coded and I'm really happy with the results (first ever finished application!). It's a phone book coded in WPF, and I'm using a DataGrid to simply store the values of the people added. The thing is I can add people and it's all smooth until I shut it down and all stored data is lost. This always happens with all the smaller projects I've done but alot of them were just application that could run a few numbers through an equation and give me an answer and I didn't require the data I had gotten. But with my phone book I want my user to open it and use it over and over again. Thank you in advance :D

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my DataGrid isn't binded to an SQL database so i cant update it on opening after a close.

Comment: Congratulations on coding up your first complete app. Unfortunately, though, your question is not easy to answer, because it does not provide any details. [ask]. You need to post at least some code describing your data structures. [tour]

Comment: And where do you want to save the data ? Database ? Disk ? In which format ?

Comment: errr, it's quite a big with a few hundred lines but it basically gets an input from a user then puts it into a the DataGrid. And also Nawed Nabi Zada (cool name btw :o) I think it will be easiest to save it on the Disk as a save file then load up my application from that.

Answer (score 0):

There are [`Closing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Closed` events in every `Window`, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your question is a little vague, but here's a worked example for you using binary serialization to create a file with your data in isolated storage (see [MSDN Isolated Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.110).aspx))

I assume you have some kind of backing class for your `DataGrid` so in this case, I have created a class called Contact. Note the `[Serializable]` attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class Contact {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Number { get; set; }

    public Contact(String name, String number) {
       Name = name;
       Number = number;
    }
}
```

I then have a list of these:

```
private List<Contact> contacts;
```

You can override the `OnClosing` method of your `Window` and then save your data down to a file:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) {
    base.OnClosing(e);
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null)) {
        if (isoStore.FileExists("contacts.dat")) {
            // We already have an old one, delete it
            isoStore.DeleteFile("contacts.dat");
        }
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = isoStore.CreateFile("contacts.dat")) {
           BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
           bf.Serialize(fs, contacts);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally after you have done whatever initialisation you need to do, you can look for this file and restore your contacts if they are there as below. Note I have added some dummy entries if there is no backup:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null)) {
    if (isoStore.FileExists("contacts.dat")) {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = isoStore.OpenFile("contacts.dat", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        contacts = (List<Contact>) bf.Deserialize(fs);
    }else {
        // We don't have a backup file, create some dummy entries
        contacts = new List<Contact>();
        contacts.Add(new Contact("John Smith", "1234567"));
        contacts.Add(new Contact("Emma Brown", "7654321"));
    }
}
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = contacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ItemsSource of your DataGrid should be set or bound to an IEnumerable<T>. To save the data to a file on disk you could then serialize all items in this IEnumerable<T> to a file. You then deserialize it back again when the application starts. The following sample code should give you the idea.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private const string _fileName = "phonebook.txt";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            //create a List<Item> that contains the data from the file on a background thread
            Task.Run(() => LoadData()).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                //...and set the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to the returned List<Item>
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = task.Result;
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        };

        this.Closing += (s, e) => SaveData();
    }

    public List<Item> LoadData()
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(_fileName))
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(_fileName);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] columns = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (columns.Length == 2)
                {
                    items.Add(new Item()
                    {
                        Name = columns[0],
                        Number = columns[1]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //populate the DataGrid with some default data...
            items.Add(new Item { Name = "Name1", Number = "000-111" });
            items.Add(new Item { Name = "Name2", Number = "111-222" });
        }

        return items;
    }

    private void SaveData()
    {
        IEnumerable<Item> items = dataGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<Item>;
        if (items != null)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_fileName))
                foreach (Item item in items)
                    sw.WriteLine($"{item.Name};{item.Number}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Item.cs:**

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

The "phonebook.txt" file will be saved in the output directory - typically c:\YourProjectFolder\bin\Debug or \bin\Release when running your application from Visual Studio - of your executable (.exe) unless you change the value of the _fileName field.